# SQL Server please help me to compare 2 table for getting the error

Tags: sql, sql-server

there is 2 tables, Table A and Table B,
Please help me the query for getting the eror if there is any difference from this tables.
Conditions :

> if item name in table A have different name from table B

and

> if item value in table A is bigger than B

and get the eror message.

[image: Example]

Thank you very much for anyone can help me..

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. As this question stands it'll probably get closed, as its not in a form we can help with. Please have a look at the [ask] page to see how to get the most from the site.

Comment: i apologize if my question too bold or offense people who read it.
and i'll read the How To Ask, and next time i hope i dont make people bad.. thanks for the advice..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are after

```
Select T1.Code,(case when T1.Item != T2.Itemthen 'Error' else 'Success' end) as ItemMessage,
       (case when T1.Val > T2.Val then 'Error' else 'Success' end) as ValueMessage,
from Table1 T1
    inner join Table2 T2 On T1.Code=T2.Code
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less a stab in the dark, pending a more complete question, but here's what I think you're asking.

First, you want to find whether any items in table B share a code with those from table A, but have different names.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.Code = b.Code
WHERE a.Name != b.Name
```

Second, you want to find any items, again matched by code, where the `Val` of B is less than or equal to that of A.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.Code = b.Code
WHERE a.Val > b.Val
```

You could, of course, alter the column list to list details of each record in each table, if need be.